# Can I use Google Cloud Armor to programmatically whitelist many IPs?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-armor

Firebase Hosting did not provide enough security, but I love the features of Firebase. So I wrote a firebase function that renders dynamic content. I put it behind a google load balancer to be able to block all traffic except whitelisted IPs.

I hope to write a function that will whitelist the IP into cloud armor after a successful sign in. I hope to whitelist as many IPs as possible (1000+) and I will add a TTL to each IP as each session expires.

My goal is to strictly limit access and prevent a DDoS attack that could potentially bring the function down and accrue charges. A bearer token is not enough for my use case.

So this is a two part question, is it possible to whitelist IPs programmatically? <s>Is there a limit to how many IPs I can whitelist?</s>

**Update:**
According to https://cloud.google.com/armor/quotas, I can have 200 rules each rule containing 10 IPs, meaning 2000 IPs. So my new question, is this an standard use case for Cloud Armor?

I understand I can get a quota increase, but there are other load balancer services such as Cloudflare with much larger IP whitelist. Although, I would like to stay within Google services.

Comment: 1) Given that Cloud Armor Plus Tier instance starts at $3,000 per month, you should really talk to your account rep who can assign the right people to help you design your system. 2) Cloud Armor has a REST API https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/securityPolicies 3) Keep in mind the more rules, the more IP lists, the slower firewalls respond. Are you designing with the right objectives in mind? 4) Using IP whitelists is not a great security model. Start thinking about authentication and authorization and not perimeters.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for the insight, i didn't keep into consideration that it could slow the firewalll down. My objective is to keep this endpoint extremely limited and allow only the right people in despite having a valid access token. I have a situation where attackers may knock down my function to prevent access for my users.

Comment: I wonder why something that's as essential and simple as IP whitelisting is limited to 2000, and why this is relevant for performance. IP whitelisting should certainly not be the foundation or sole measure of a security model, but it keeps the number of attackers (and with this the noise) down. I personally find it useful; especially to reduce accidental charges.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb) and @John Hanley recommendation you should not use IP whitelists filtering for your security model:

> Note that using static IP address filtering is not considered a safe
> and effective means of protection. Instead, we suggest that you take a defense
> in depth approach using **OAuth** and **Certs**.

Comment: I am also using authorization tokens provided by Firebase, I'm just having concerns of malicious attackers ddosing the endpoint or accruing charges. I will have to reconsider this approach, this endpoint is very private and for exclusive clients only.